# Need help deploying Windows 8 PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have developed a Windows 8 App using HTML, JS Blank App template. I have included PhoneGap / Cordova JS reference to the project as explained in PhoneGap documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html

I am able to run the application in local environment, however I want to deploy it using PhoneGap build. PhoneGap documentation does not contain any information on which files needs to be bundled as zip file and upload to PhoneGap build server.

I need help on identifying the files which needs to be deployed to PhoneGap build and the format of those files [for e.g. Zip file, folder structure inside the zip file etc]

Note - For Windows Phone 7 app developed using Visual Studio 2010, IDE itself creates 'www' folder along with required JS and CSS files, which I have successfully deployed to PhoneGap build server and verified ap on different devices.

I need help specifically for Windows 8 app.

Thanks.

Comment: Curious why you want to use PhoneGap with Windows8, since the WinJS sdk provides all the hardware integration that PhoneGap would.  (Unless you are talking about Windows Phone 8?)

Comment: Hi Ely - I would like to deploy my Windows 8 application across different platforms [iOS, Android and Windows], so the reason I am using PhoneGap. However I am not able to figure out which files I need to bundle to deploy it to PhoneGap build server. As per PhoneGap documentation for Windows 8, I have renamed default.html file to index.html, created a zip file which contains HTML, CSS and JS files from my windows app, deployed it to PhoneFap build server. It seems I am missing something since build server is going in infinite loop (just showing the progress ring...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap-Build does not support building for Windows 8, so I assume you are attempting to use PhoneGap-Build to port a PhoneGap app that you have developed for Windows 8.

The Windows8 version of Apache Cordova currently uses some of the extra WinRT.js stuff behind the scenes.  You will need to remove these references.

```
<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
```

Also, the Windows8 version of Apache Cordova is not currently using a www folder, so when putting together your zip, you may need to create it.

Zip structure should be like this:

```
MyApp.zip
+-www/
  +-cordova-2.x.0.js
  +-index.html
  +-[any other supporting files, images you use ]
```

@Ely, Yes WinRT does do all the same stuff as PhoneGap, but it is completely non-portable.

Comment: Hello PurpleCabbage - Thanks, I will try your suggested approach.

Comment: I was able to deploy the application by commenting out WinJS references as you suggested, however PhoneGap notification alert pop-up was not displayed as expected. Below is the source code I have added in <body> tag in index.html

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            navigator.notification.alert("device is ready");
        });
    </script>
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you are @PrasadHonrao When I run the application it fails on navigator.notification.alert... have you ever figured it out?

Comment: Apologies for delayed response @Michael, but I did not find any solution on it.